# How to copy programatically a directory located inside the system root on a an android rooted device

Tags: java, android, root

I would like to be able (within an app) to copy  programmatically a  directory located int the system root of a an android rooted device to the SD card. I would also like to be able to filter files based on last modification and be able to deal with Symlink (copying the Symlink not the target). Is it possible to do this using File.java or do I need to use shell command to access root system files ? What is the best way to do this ?

TIA

Edit : one problem I have with File.java is that it will work for the the path "/" which is the root directory but not for subdir like "/data" for which files will return null in the code below :

File directory= new File("/data")
File[] files = directory.listFiles();

Comment: That is not caused by the File class but by Android OS that made that subdir inaccessable.

Comment: Try "/system" and you will see.

Comment: I know, this is what I pointed to therefore my question what is the best way to do this ? It is possible using shell command like Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cp -a  "+sourcedir+" "+targetdir); but may be there is some better way